# creating the dictionary of array in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing the app for kids and I need to Create a dictionary of the array as like {"A":[apple, Ant, Airplane], "B":[....],...}. And from that, I need to get the value as A for Apple, A for Ant, Airplane.
 I tried with code:

```
 alphabetsStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.png",@"b.png",@"c.png",@"d.png",@"e.png",@"f.png",@"g.png",@"h.png",@"i.png",@"j.png",@"k.png",@"l.png",@"m.png",@"n.png",@"o.png",@"p.png",@"q.png",@"r.png",@"s.png",@"t.png",@"u.png",@"v.png",@"w.png",@"x.png",@"y.png",@"z.png", nil];
```

But I need to get as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
NSMutableArray *arrForA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Ant", @"Arc", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrForB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ball", @"Bat", @"Box", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dictAlpha = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: arrForA, @"A", arrForB, @"B", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dictAlpha); // 1

NSArray *keys=[dictAlpha allKeys];


for (int i = 0; i< keys.count; i++) {

    NSArray *arrVal = [dictAlpha objectForKey:keys[i]];

    for (int j=0; j<arrVal.count; j++) {
        NSLog(@"%@ for %@", keys[i], arrVal[j]); // 2
    }

}
```

**Output**

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: can u provide in if condition please

Comment: @jesti Which If condition?

Comment: i need the above code u given in if statement condition

Answer (score 2):

You can do like,

```
NSArray *arrA = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"AeroPlane",@"Ant", nil];

NSArray *arrB = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ball",@"Baloon",@"Banana", nil];

NSArray *arrC = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cat",@"Car",@"Cow", nil];

NSDictionary *resultDictionary = @{@"A" : arrA, @"B" : arrB, @"C" : arrC} ;
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"A":@[@"Apple",@"Ant",.....],
                       @"B":@[@"Ball",@"Bat",.....],
                       @"C":@[@"Call",@"Cat",.....],
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       };
```

Comment: thanks.but i also need to get the value apple from that

Comment: HOW TO GET THE VALUES

Comment: it's really simple from here. Just try it for your self. All you have to do it read from a dictionary. Like this [data valueForKey:@"a"]

Answer (score 1):

```
// A dictionary object
NSDictionary *dict; 

// Create array to hold   dictionaries 

NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictionaries = [NSMutableArray    array];

// Create three dictionaries 

dict = [NSDictionary    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   // Key value pairs
                    @"Bock", style,    
                    @"Deep Gold", appearance, 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:25], hopProfile, 
                    nil]; 
arrayOfDictionaries addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   // Key value pairs  
                    @"India Pale Ale (IPA)", style, 
                    @"Copper", appearance, 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:50], hopProfile, 
                    nil]; 

[arrayOfDictionaries addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Stout", style, 
                  @"Jet Black", appearance, 
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:35], hopProfile, 
                  nil]; 

[arrayOfDictionaries addObject:dict]; 

NSLog(@"array of dictionaries: %@", arrayOfDictionaries);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I recommend using some local variables (or global constants if these values are fixed) to make it more readable, but you can just create an `NSMutableDictionary` that takes the `key` as an `NSString` for the each value of the alphabet. And the `value` can be the array.

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *>> *alphabetDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Then you can add each array to the dictionary.
// For example:

NSString *keyA = @"A";
NSArray<NSString *> *arrayForA = @[ @"Aardvark", @"Apple" ];
[alphabetDict setValue:arrayForA forKey:keyA];

// Repeat to add each array to the dict.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily mix match in objective c.

```
NSMutableDictionary *alphabets = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
alphabets["a"] = @["apple", "ant", "airplane", nil];
aplhabets["b"] = @["boy", "big", nil];
```

Comment: `sorry code can have some syntax issue!!` - you wrote this line in answer! If you know that there is issue in code then you should not write answer!  And your code have issues before editing also! that's why down vote ! Btw now you have edited answer so I am retracting it!